# Exception while connecting to the database

Tags: java, mysql

When I run this code:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/staion_meteo";// phpmyadmin
String user = "root";
String passwd="" ;
Connection conn  = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
System.out.println("you are connected to the data base : "+"station_meteo");
```

I get the following exception:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/staion_meteo

Comment: You need to make sure that the MySQL JDBC driver is in your classpath.

Comment: Have you added the Jar file for MySQL - `mysql-connector.jar` in the classpath?

Comment: thx a lot mans ^^ I forgot to add mysql-connector.jar :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

before your connection. Also make sure `mysql-connector.jar` in your class path.

Answer (score 1):

Do this first ...

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```